# sortby the name by alphabet in array list using lodash

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

how to sort the name in array list by alphabet in javascript, I tried with this code

```
const sample = [
    {
        name: "AddMain",
        mesg: "test000"
    },
    {
        name: "Ballside",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "TestMain",
        mesg: "test00"
    },
    {
        name: "ball",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "Main",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "alliswell",
        mesg: "test004545"
    }
]

sample.sort(sortBy('name', false, function(a){return a.toUpperCase()}));
```

but it not working properly in this code sortBy I am using lodash. if it possible in lodash it will to fine

Comment: _how to sort the name in array_ or sort array by name ? what are the expected results ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
const sample = [
    {
        name: "AddMain",
        mesg: "test000"
    },
    {
        name: "Ballside",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "TestMain",
        mesg: "test00"
    },
    {
        name: "ball",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "Main",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "alliswell",
        mesg: "test004545"
    }
];


var chars =_.orderBy(sample, [user => user.name.toLowerCase()], ['asc']);
 
console.log(chars);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[According to the lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy) the API of `sortBy` is:

`_.sortBy(collection, [iteratees=[_.identity]])`

In your case, the `collection` is your `sample` array and your `[iteratees=[_.identity]]` should be a function or an array which returns the key you want to sort.

So this is probably what you were going for:

`_.sortBy(sample, ['name']);`

OR

`_.sortBy(sample, function(o){return o.name;}]);`

Answer (score 1):

## [_.sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy)

Your code should be like:

**DEMO**

```js
const sample = [{
  name: "AddMain",
  mesg: "test000"
}, {
  name: "Ballside",
  mesg: "test004545"
}, {
  name: "TestMain",
  mesg: "test00"
}, {
  name: "ball",
  mesg: "test004545"
}, {
  name: "Main",
  mesg: "test004545"
}, {
  name: "alliswell",
  mesg: "test004545"
}];

let result = _.sortBy(sample, ({name}) => name.toLowerCase());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="//lodash.com/vendor/cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sample = [
    {
        name: "AddMain",
        mesg: "test000"
    },
    {
        name: "Ballside",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "TestMain",
        mesg: "test00"
    },
    {
        name: "ball",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "Main",
        mesg: "test004545"
    },
    {
        name: "alliswell",
        mesg: "test004545"
    }
]

var result = sample.slice().sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const characters = [
  { name: 'Jean-Luc Picard', age: 59 },
  { name: 'William Riker', age: 29 },
  { name: 'Deanna Troi', age: 28 },
  { name: 'Worf', age: 24 }
];

// Sort characters by the `age` property
const sorted = _.sortBy(characters, 'age');

console.log(sorted);

sorted[0].name; // Worf
sorted[1].name; // Deanna Troi
sorted[2].name; // William Riker
sorted[3].name; // Jean-Luc Picard
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.js"></script>
```